# Use .so and .com file packaged into .aar library

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have two files a .so file located in /jni/armeabi-v7a and a .com file located in /assets/armeabi-v7a.

Normally those two files are integrated into the application.

For my project, i need to embed those two files in a .aar library.

Did i have only to configure this on the application build.gradle :
android.ndk

```
    moduleName = "dbr"
    ldFlags.add("-L<static library path>")
    ldLibs.addAll(["twolib-first"])
```

Or did i need to configure others things ?

Best regards,

David